# doctrine with softDelete inside relation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

Hi all I have a problem about softdelete inside relation.

For the softdelete I'm using `Gedmo\SoftDeleteable` and this is my entity (I have cut a lot of things)

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as JMS;


/**
 * Item
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="item")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ItemRepository")
 * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt", timeAware=false)
 */
class Item implements EntityInterface
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

   /**
     * One Item has Many Images.
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Image", mappedBy="item", cascade="remove")
     * @MaxDepth(1)
     * @JMS\Groups({"images"})
     */
    private $images;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="deleted_at", type="datetime", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $deletedAt;

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->images = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    public function addImage(\AppBundle\Entity\Image $image)
    {
        $this->images[] = $image;

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeImage(\AppBundle\Entity\Image $image)
    {
        $this->images->removeElement($image);
    }

    public function getImages()
    {
        return $this->images;
    }

    public function getImagePreview()
    {
        foreach($this->getImages() as $image){
            if ($image->getPreview()) {
                return substr($image->getPath(), strpos($image->getPath(), "/images/") + 8);
            }
        }

        return '';
    }

    public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
    {
        $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

        return $this;
    }


    public function getDeletedAt()
    {
        return $this->deletedAt;
    }
}
```

I have some images deleted and inside my database when an image is deleted field deleted_at are compiled so if I make a `findAll` with doctrine automatically that records not return

But if I call getImages from my template I retrieve all images also deleted images, but I don't want It.

This is how I call getImages from my template inside a loop:

```
foreach($lot->getImages() as $image) { 
    //code
}
```

how can I use function `getImages` to retrieve only images not deleted?

Thanks

P.S. I don't want to insert an `if condition` inside the template, I wanna solve It in the backend

Comment: Awesome, no solutions here.  Did you find a good resolution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine has 2 methods of operation for entities: either `EntityPersister` or `DQL` through `QueryBuilder`. For simple queries like `findAll` Doctrine will choose the `BasicEntityPersister` to perform your query.

Now, the problem is that Gedmo does not scan associations of executed entities, it is only focused on the current query. In the first `EntityPersister` mode it will never add the required condition because of the lack of association awareness. Your could trick working it using the second mode, with a QueryBuilder and `innerJoin` with the `Images` entity - that would be the fastest solution for you.

I came with a complex solution for the `BasicEntityPersister` and it works. Here are the steps:

1. Create a new EntityManager extending `EntityManagerDecorator` and decorate the service:

```
    entity_manager_proxy:
        public: false
        class: App\Doctrine\EntityManagerProxy
        decorates: doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager
        arguments: [ "@entity_manager_proxy.inner" ]
```

2. Create a decorator for the UOW and invoke it within the new EM:

```
  public function getUnitOfWork()
    {
        return new UnitOfWorkProxy($this);
    }
```

3. Inside your UOW proxy you are now able to override the `EntityPersister` as you wish. I did like this:

```
  public function getEntityPersister($entityName)
    {
        $persister = parent::getEntityPersister($entityName);

        // we are only hooking up the common persister
        if (!$persister instanceof BasicEntityPersister) {
            return $persister;
        }

        $class = $this->em->getClassMetadata($entityName);

        return new SoftDeleteableBasicEntityPersister(
            $this->em,
            $class
        );
    }
```

4. Here's the actual code that does the trick: scans the associations and adds the required condition. Luckily, I didn't have to overwrite the whole `getSelectColumnsSQL` method:

```
    protected function getSelectColumnsSQL()
    {
        // luckily we don't need to modify the SQL created, but a property in the context
        $sql = parent::getSelectColumnsSQL();

        $aliasCounter = 0;

        // we'll be going through all associations and find those with the soft-deleted trait
        foreach ($this->class->associationMappings as $assocField => $mapping) {
            $targetEntityClass = $mapping['targetEntity'];

            if (!$this->isSoftDeleted($targetEntityClass)) {
                continue;
            }

            if (!$mapping['isOwningSide']) {
                continue;
            }

            $targetEntityClassMetadata = $this->em->getClassMetadata($targetEntityClass);
            if ($mapping['mappedBy'] !== null) {
                $association = $targetEntityClassMetadata->getAssociationMapping($mapping['mappedBy']);
            } else {
                $association = $mapping;
            }
            $assocAlias = 's' . ($aliasCounter++);

            $joinTableAlias = $this->getSQLTableAlias($targetEntityClassMetadata->name, $assocAlias);
            $joinTableName  = $this->quoteStrategy->getTableName($targetEntityClassMetadata, $this->platform);

            $tableAlias = $this->getSQLTableAlias($association['targetEntity'], $assocAlias);

            // if we're sure our entity has a relation with a soft-deleted entity,
            // let's add an INNER JOIN to prevent from listing those which were deleted
            $this->currentPersisterContext->selectJoinSql .= ' INNER JOIN';

            foreach ($association['joinColumns'] as $joinColumn) {
                $sourceCol       = $this->quoteStrategy->getJoinColumnName($joinColumn, $this->class, $this->platform);
                $targetCol       = $this->quoteStrategy->getReferencedJoinColumnName($joinColumn, $this->class, $this->platform);
                $joinCondition[] = $this->getSQLTableAlias($association['sourceEntity'])
                    . '.' . $sourceCol . ' = ' . $tableAlias . '.' . $targetCol;
            }

            // Add filter SQL
            $filterSql = $this->generateFilterConditionSQL($targetEntityClassMetadata, $tableAlias);
            if ($filterSql) {
                $joinCondition[] = $filterSql;
            }

            // the result of our operation is stored inside the context
            // luckily this will be pulled into the main SQL later
            $this->currentPersisterContext->selectJoinSql .= ' ' . $joinTableName . ' ' . $joinTableAlias . ' ON ';
            $this->currentPersisterContext->selectJoinSql .= implode(' AND ', $joinCondition);
        }

        return $sql;
    }
```

For Doctrine 2.4 it works, but may change/break with future versions of Doctrine, if they allow modifying queries in a more consistent way.

As for the DQL/QueryBuilder operation method, you need to override the `EntityRepository` and `QueryBuilder` in a similar fashion, then basically you can manipulate around the `getQuery()` method as you wish, using a Hint for SqlWalkers etc. I can provide a solution if needed

Hope it helps!